# Access 2007: closing form and opening next form with matching EmpName

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I've searched here for answers that seem to be asking this question but none of the answers were good enough to work for me.

I want to have a NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons on some forms.

Next would close the "CurrentForm" and open the "NextForm" . Previous would close "CurrentForm", and open the "PreviousForm".

The field they all share is called "Personnel" , which is the EmpName basically.

So far I have been working on this: (what I did was simply creating a button to "open form" from the WIZARD, but it's not working?)

```
Private Sub cmdPrevAD1_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdPrevAD1_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "frmComp_Events_2013"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_cmdPrevAD1_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdPrevAD1_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdPrevAD1_Click

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

```
     Dim stDocName As String
     Dim sEmpName As String

     stDocName = "frmComp_Events_2013"
     sEmpName = Me.Personnel.Value
     DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , "Personnel = '" & sEmpName & "'"
```

**The above edit solved the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, showing forms is done by the `Show` method. This could open the form you need. A related method is the `Hide` method, which could hide the first form so you don't have more than one displaying at a time.

For more info, check out MS help - in the VBA editor, press **F1**.

Comment: I still need them to open up to the right entry in the form. For example, the name should line up.

Comment: Also the F1 Show Method example shows only two forms but I have more than two. I want to cycle between multiple forms with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The code you display seems legit. are you closing the current form before opening the previous/next form? that would be a problem because the code stops running before you it can open an other form. you need open you new form first and then close you current form.

I hope this helped

Comment: It does open the form I want, but the name doesn't match up. E.g. I'm on form with name "Vladimir" which is record number 333 but when I press open form, it takes me to record number 1 in the new form.